# I need help parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing

When I console.log the data that I am getting, I'm getting an object that looks like this (I trimmed some stuff to make it look more readable and the ... is basically a repeat of the info with different values):

```
[ Submission {
    title: 'Untitled',
    content:
     { url: 'http://orig00.deviantart.net/8791/f/2016/079/7/b/untitled_by_wecode-d9vvg2w.png',
       height: '400',
       width: '400',
       medium: 'image' },
    text: null },
  Submission {
    ...
     },
  Submission {
    ...
     } ]
```

I want to grab the url from content in each submission. At the end, I should get an array with multiple urls. I'm working in nodejs if that is of any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have an array of Objects here - let's assume it's stored in a variable called `myArray`. To get a new list of just the URLs, you can do:

```
var listOfUrls = [];
myArray.forEach(function(obj) {
    listOfUrls.push(obj.content.url);
}
```

This will give you the array you want. This is a simple way to do it, but you can also do it in other ways such as `map`

Comment: .map is more consise

Comment: I would say that's a matter of perspective. For someone new to javascript, a `forEach` loop might be more readable and easier to understand than `map` would be. Of course, that's no reason not to use `map`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap), which creates a new array by applying the function to each element in the old array.

```
var arrayOfSubmissions = ...
var arrayOfURLs = arrayOfSubmissions.map(function(submission){
    return submission.content.url
})
```

Answer (score 2):

`.map` is your friend. It iterates over every item of an array and will add whatever each run of a function returns to a new array.

```
var urls = yourArray.map(function (item) {
   return item.content.url;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourObject = [{
    Submission: {
        title: 'Untitled',
        content: {
            url: 'http://orig00.deviantart.net/8791/f/2016/079/7/b/untitled_by_wecode-d9vvg2w.png',
            height: '400',
            width: '400',
            medium: 'image'
        },
        text: null
    }
}];

// your new array of url's
var urls = [];

for (i = 0; i < yourObject.length; i++) {
    urls.push(yourObject[i].Submission.content.url);
}
```